# Disabled area for scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

There is a website

[image: selectedscroll]

How to display the scroll bar (as in the screenshot - highlighted in red)?

```css
#dropdownwindow {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 5;
    /*display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
    "left search search search"
    "left right right right";
    grid-area: mainwindowpart;*/
}
    
#fullblock {
    height: 100vh;
    /*display: grid;*/
    /*grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "mainwindowpart freespace";*/
    position: static;
}
/*
.CatalogMenuLeft{
    grid-area: left;
    display: none;
}

.CatalogMenuRight{
    grid-area: right;
    display: none;
}

.CatalogMenuSearch {
    grid-area: search;
    display: none;
}

.CatalogFreeSpace {
    grid-area: freespace;
    display: none;
}*/

.contentdropdownwindow {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindow">
        <div class="crossline">
            <div class="close">&times;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contentdropdownwindow">
            <div class="CatalogMenuLeft">
                    <h1>Каталог</h1>
                    <div >
                        Смартфоны и гаджеты
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Ноутбуки и компьютеры
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Телевизоры, аудио-видео, Hi-Fi
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Бытовая техника для дома и кухни
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Строительство и ремонт
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Дом и дача
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Фото, видео, системы безопасности
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Автотовары
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        
                    </div>                  
            </div>
            <div class="myscroll">
            
            </div>
            <div class="centerdropdownwindow">
                    <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--<div>-->        
<!--</div>-->
</div>
```

What code should be put instead

```
<div class = "myscroll">

</div>
```

? (give all the possibilities please - I'm a beginner).

2. How can you make the top of the scrollbar inactive (light gray on top to red)? Important that the top part of the scrollbar was inactive.

Comment: How to display scroll bar? Or scrollbar as per the design provided? (Slim etc)?

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll;` on the element you wish to have a scroll bar for overflow

Comment: @AbinThaha Important that the top part of the scrollbar was inactive?

Comment: Ok, so there is some disabled area for scroll bar, then the scroll starts after certain space from top? is that what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @AbinThaha Yes see for example https://www.citilink.ru/

Comment: Consider them as two independent div's and give scrollbar only for the bottom one, while to the above one, use some kind of a border-right and will work as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

To display a scroll bar, no additional CSS is required. apart from `overflow-y: scroll` and when the length of content of the container is more than the container height, it will automatically show up. And if you want to style the scroll bar differently you can add a custom css. For example something as below code snippet:

More samples to style here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

```css
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
```

Comment: Important that the top part of the scrollbar was inactive. See comments for AbinThaba

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are talking about how to style a scrollbar, here's how:

`::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 10px; color: gray; }`

Comment: It has browser restrictions?

Comment: @BinayakKarki Important that the top part of the scrollbar was inactive. See comments for AbinThaba

Comment: @BinayakKarki Firefox support required.

Answer (score 0):

If you check here, the above area of scrollbar is disabled

```css
header {
  border-right: 5px solid #ddd;
  height: 50px;
}

div {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.div1 {
  min-height: 500px
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #ddd; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Hi there
</header>
<div>
<div class='div1'>content goes here</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @AbinThaba And how to style for firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Here, it will not actually disable it but will make it look disabled:

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: calc(30vw - 16px);
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: calc(70vw - 16px);
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.top-part {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.bottom-part {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.top-part::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.bottom-part::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b30000;
}
```

```html
<div class='left'>
  <div class='top-part'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class='bottom-part'>
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Donec vel turpis.</li>
      <li>Nunc sagittis.</li>
      <li>Proin fringilla risus.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='right'>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa
    <strong>strong</strong>. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet
    nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede <a class="external ext" href="#">link</a> mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean
    vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam
    ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.</p>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit
  </h1>
  <h2>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor aenean massa</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem.</p>
  <h2>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor aenean massa</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer.</li>
    <li>Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</li>
    <li>Aenean massa cum sociis natoque penatibus.</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem.</p>
  <table class="data" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Entry Header 1</th>
      <th>Entry Header 2</th>
      <th>Entry Header 3</th>
      <th>Entry Header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Entry First Line 1</td>
      <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
      <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
      <td>Entry First Line 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Entry Line 1</td>
      <td>Entry Line 2</td>
      <td>Entry Line 3</td>
      <td>Entry Line 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Entry Last Line 1</td>
      <td>Entry Last Line 2</td>
      <td>Entry Last Line 3</td>
      <td>Entry Last Line 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem.</p>
</div>
```